# Airflow: calling one operator from another

Tags: airflow

```py
    def func(**kwargs):
            print(config['rds_conn_id'])
            rds = PostgresHooklog(postgres_conn_id=config['rds_conn_id'])
            rds.set_autocommit(rds.get_conn(), True)
            conn = rds
            print(conn)
            # a = []
            previous_e = None
            for i in range(0, 1):
                a = TriggerDagRunOperator(
                        task_id='test_trigger_dagrun'+str(i),
                        trigger_dag_id="example1_trigger_target_dag",
                        provide_context=True,
                        params={'message': 'Hello world'},
                        trigger_rule="all_done",
                        dag=dag,
                    )
                if previous_e:
                    previous_e >> a
                a
                previous_e = a
                # a.execute(dict({ 'message': 'Hello world'}))
                # if i not in [0]:
                #     a[i - 1] >> a[i]
    
    default_args={"owner": "airflow", "start_date": days_ago(2)}
    
    # Define the DAG
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id="example1_trigger_controller_dag",
        default_args={"owner": "airflow", "start_date": days_ago(2)},
        schedule_interval="@once",
        tags=['example']
    )
    with dag:
    # Define the single task in this controller example DAG
        bhuvitest = PythonOperator(
            task_id='python_task',
            python_callable=func,
            dag=dag)
```

I want to call TriggerDagRunOperator inside PythonOperator thru function and that will fetch some records from the database. Based on the records iterate over the loop and call TriggerDagRunOperator.

1. How to make each iteration sequential instead of parallel. which not working in this case even it is not calling TriggerDagRunOperator.
2. I want to pass some parameters in TriggerDagRunOperator to target dag in this case variable message as an argument but that is also not working.

I really appreciate your help.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using operators as you did is not allowed in Airflow. All the operators must live in the DAG context. As mentioned in [Airflow official tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#it-s-a-dag-definition-file), the DAG definition "needs to evaluate quickly (seconds, not minutes) since the scheduler will execute it periodically to reflect the changes if any". So it's not recommended to query a database to create a DAG "on the fly".

That being said, you can use `Variables` to dynamically define a DAG, or even a local file to the workers (that's more complicated if you have more than one workers). None of both are "good practices", but you can still use it. For the `Variables` option, you could have two DAGs, one for querying the database and setting the configuration variable and the other to read it, loop through it and create the tasks. That's also not very recommended since you're going to create connections to the metadata DB every time you do `Variable.get("variable_name")`.

To your questions:

1. To make it sequential just iterate with `for idx, val in enumerate(iterable)` and do something like:

```py
if idx > 0:
    iterable[idx - 1] >> iterable[idx]
```

2. To pass some parameters you can use the `conf` argument from [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It works for me thru variables. here is a useful link if anyone is facing the same problem: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dynamic-workflows-airflow-kyle-bridenstine/

Comment: Great to hear that @AnujSingh! Remember to mark the question as answered and upvote if the solution provided works for you.